# How to convert/align my uint8_t pointer buffer to uint32 for it to work with auto-generated HAL functions

Tags: c, stm32

In my auto-generated HAL code for implementing CRC I have the following function:

```
uint32_t HAL_CRC_Accumulate(CRC_HandleTypeDef *hcrc, uint32_t pBuffer[], uint32_t BufferLength)
{
  uint32_t index;      /* CRC input data buffer index */
  uint32_t temp = 0U;  /* CRC output (read from hcrc->Instance->DR register) */

  /* Change CRC peripheral state */
  hcrc->State = HAL_CRC_STATE_BUSY;

  switch (hcrc->InputDataFormat)
  {
    case CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_WORDS:
      /* Enter Data to the CRC calculator */
      for (index = 0U; index < BufferLength; index++)
      {
        hcrc->Instance->DR = pBuffer[index];
      }
      temp = hcrc->Instance->DR;
      break;

    case CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES:
      temp = CRC_Handle_8(hcrc, (uint8_t *)pBuffer, BufferLength);
      break;

    case CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_HALFWORDS:
      temp = CRC_Handle_16(hcrc, (uint16_t *)(void *)pBuffer, BufferLength);    /* Derogation MisraC2012 R.11.5 */
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  /* Change CRC peripheral state */
  hcrc->State = HAL_CRC_STATE_READY;

  /* Return the CRC computed value */
  return temp;
}
```

The problem is that my own inBuff is of type `uint8_t * inBuff` and I can see in the auto-generated code that it needs a uint32_t as input, and also later on just typecasts it to a uint8_t as i use the CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES option for my CRC. The reason for needing my uint8_t buff is to make it work with the rest of my code (pretty big project). Is there any reason to work around this in an efficient way without damaging my own inBuff content? It needs to be aligned correctly.

Comment: What is there to work around? Just pass the buffer. `It needs to be aligned correctly.` why? To what alignment?

Comment: `HAL_CRC_Accumulate` can't be salvaged since it contains undefined behavior here: `(uint16_t *)(void *)pBuffer`.

Comment: Do you have to change your auto-generated code frequently? After all, that code is just created for your convenience. You are free to change it according to your needs. It is just a bit more effort to keep an eye on your own changes when autogenerating the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- A function which does not intend to access a pointer parameter through the pointed-at type should not be declared with that type. If `HAL_CRC_Accumulate` never intends to access `pBuffer` as an (array of) `uint32_t` then it shouldn't be using that type. It should then have been declared as `uint8_t*`.
- Passing an `uint8_t*` pointing at the first item of an array to a function accepting `uint32_t*` is highly fishy code and could indeed cause misalignment problems. Most of your problems boils down to: *why does this function use uint32_t[]*? It doesn't make any sense.
- Casting a `uint32*` to a `uint16_t*` is similarly bad practice and undefined behavior in case the function that this `uint16_t*` is passed to will access that parameter as `uint16_t`. Not only because of possible misalignment but also because of strict aliasing. Again, if that function has no intention of using the `uint16_t*` to access a `uint16_t` object, then it shouldn't be using that pointer type. Again, it seems like this whole code should be working on `uint8_t*` types.
- "Chaining" multiple casts like this `(uint16_t *)(void *)` is nonsense. The `void*` adds nothing and solves nothing.
- Normally a function that calculates CRC would work on a `const` qualified buffer, because it isn't supposed to change anything. If the so-called "FCS" (calculated checksum) should be appended at the end of the data buffer, then it might be better design to do that separately.
- Since MISRA-C is mentioned in comments: all of the above is particularly unacceptable in a mission-critical code base. Auto-generated code is no excuse for sloppy, potentially broken use of types - on the contrary. More importantly than advisory rule 11.5, you have multiple violations of (Required) MISRA-C:2012 rule 11.3 and none of this is MISRA compliant.

Comment: So would the best way be to actually modify the auto-generated HAL-code to use uint8_t const buffer instead of uint32_t? As the functions aren't well constructed.

Comment: @Beyondthevoid Yes, the code as-is cannot be used in a professional context. I wouldn't trust the tool that auto-generated it either.

Comment: Modifying the auto-generated HAL code is not a good idea.  It will get stomped every time you regenerate the project...a real pain in the ass!  Can you just create your own module with your version of the function and call that instead?

Comment: @CraigB The point is rather that a code generator tool spitting out code like this shouldn't be used for any purpose, least of all for MISRA-C applications.

Comment: By the way, the "locking" of the CRC peripheral (the writes to `hcrc->State`) is highly doubtful as well, as is the case for almost all STM HAL functions, unfortunately. They do not support multi-threading, so I'm not sure why you would set the state in this function.

Answer (score 2):

STMCubeMX does NOT generate the best code and you have found a good example of this.

First of all, they(ST) DO want you to pass in a uint32_t buffer because they  want the data aligned on a 32-bit boundary.  See this line:

```
hcrc->Instance->DR = pBuffer[index];
```

They are expecting to read a uint32_t value and write it to the 32-bit DR register.  A misaligned pointer would cause a fault right there.

You trying to cast your uint8_t buffer to a uint32_t could be problematic if the buffer isn't actually aligned on a 32-bit boundary.  You could align yours like this:

```
uint8_t mybuf[128] __attribute__((aligned(4)));
```

You would still need to cast your pointer to a uint32_t* to pass it to HAL_CRC_Accumulate so the compiler wouldn't complain, BUT it would work because it is really aligned!

I would highly encourage you to NOT modify code generated by CubeMX.  Unless your code is added within special /* USER */ sections of the ST code, it will be lost each time you regenerate the project.  This will bite you in the ass over and over and over.

Comment: Code for 8 bit data: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF3/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_crc.c#L443
Code for 16-bit data: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF3/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_crc.c#L493
`pBuffer` is only accessed through the 32-bit pointer when the configuration tells it so.

Comment: Just so I get this right. I declare my buff like you did:
uint8_t mybuf[128] __attribute__((aligned(4)));
I then add the following in-param:
const uint8_t  * const mybuf
And call the function:
HAL_CRC_Accumulate(&hcrc, (uint32_t*)mybuf), bufLen); 
? 

Will I be able to have uint16_t as a return value in my function with the in-param?

Comment: @wovano I did type that I am using format bytes for InputDataFormat in my post if I'm not mistaken? If I want to receive a uint16_t instead of the uint32_t that it returns. Could I just use uint16_t lowerBytes = (uint16_t) (result & 0xFFFFUL); then? where "result" is the returned value from the HAL function? To only return the lower uint16_t out of the uint32_t?

Comment: @Beyondthevoid, sorry you're right. I just re-read your queston and noticed that you did mention that. So in that case, the code will work (except for all kinds of theoretical problematic issues with it), and it will always return a 32-bit result.

Comment: @Beyondthevoid, looking at the code mentioned in above comment, it seems the CRC is really 32-bit, and the buffer size will only determine how the memory is read (regarding alignment, etc.). Whether taking only the 16 lowest bits of the CRC is a good approach is a completely different question (and the short answer is no). CRCs are determined in a very specific way, and just getting the lowest 16 bits completely defeats the purpose I think. For simple (non-critical) use cases it might be sufficient though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess I can simply allow it to return a uint32_t to avoid further issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Allocate your buffer to the desired size plus `sizeof(uint32_t) - 1`.

For example, if you buffer is statically allocated to `SIZE`, then you can do:

```
uint8_t buff[SIZE + sizeof(uint32_t) - 1];
```

2. Set your pointer to the lowest address within your buffer, which aligned to `uint32_t`:

```
size_t addr = (size_t)buff + sizeof(uint32_t) - 1;
uint8_t* inBuff = (uint8_t*)(addr / sizeof(uint32_t) * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: I don't think you are guaranteed to get a 32-bit aligned buffer when it is declared as a uint8_t.  Generally the compiler will start new definitions on an aligned address, but I don't think it's guaranteed.

Comment: @CraigB: That's why I allocate an additional amount of 3 bytes, then set the pointer to the first address within that buffer which IS aligned to 4 bytes. There is guaranteed to be such address, with still a sufficient amount of memory (`SIZE` in the example above) allocated past that address.

Comment: indeed what you say would work as long as you make sure to use the first aligned address in the buffer and it's sufficiently long enough for your data.  I'm not sure why you would go to this trouble when you could guarantee the alignment by using the align attribute like this: uint8_t mybuf[128] __attribute__((aligned(4)));   or by declaring your buffer as a uint32_t buffer.  But your approach does work.

Comment: @CraigB: 1. afaik, `__attribute__` is an extension outside of the language standard. 2. This user has requested 'How to convert/align my uint8_t pointer buffer to uint32', so I've assumed that he is not allowed to simply use a `uint32_t` buffer (otherwise, what's the challenge?).

Answer (score -2):

> How to convert/align my uint8_t pointer buffer to uint32 for it to work with auto-generated HAL functions

Do nothing.

> The problem is that my own inBuff is of type uint8_t * inBuff and I can see in the auto-generated code that it needs a uint32_t as input

So cast the pointer.

```
HAL_CRC_Accumulate(..., (uint32_t*)your_buffer, ...)
```

> Is there any reason to work around this in an efficient way without damaging my own inBuff content?

No. (?)

Yes, it is unpleasant that it doesn't take a `void*` pointer or that there aren't just separate API for each INPUTDATA_FORMAT. Still, there is nothing for you to do, just pass the pointer value - the internal routines will access them via `uint8_t*` proper handle anyway.

The alignment needed for INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES is 1, at bytes boundaries.

Comment: The main problem here is that the function is broken by implementation due to aliasing problems and nothing in the caller code can fix it. Also wildly casting a `uint8_t*` to `uint32_t*` can give misaligned access.

Comment: @Lundin the data is never accessed via a uint32_t pointer, as long the input data format is set correctly. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Armandas `CRC_Handle_16` for some reason takes a `uint16_t*` though so it is fairly safe to assume it accesses data through 16 bit word access. Or alternatively whoever wrote the `CRC_Handle_16` function didn't know what they were doing. Similarly, if you never intend to access a passed `uint32_t*` parameter as a `uint32_t` lvalue then why on earth did you pick that pointer type? It is very smelly code either way and these functions need to be fixed.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but in that case the original data should be in uint16_t, so no problem.

Comment: @Armandas, when a function takes a pointer to uint32_t buffer, you need to assume that the function accesses it as aligned uint32_t data and your data should be properly aligned for this.  Just because you were able to inspect this function in this case and think it doesn't actually access the data at uint32_t, is not justification.  In fact, the function DOES access the data as uint32_t values.  This line "hcrc->Instance->DR = pBuffer[index];" is reading a uint32_t right from the pointer and writing it to the DR register.  A misaligned pointer would cause a fault right there.

Comment: @CraigB as you can see the line you're referring to is only executed when input data is 32 bits: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF3/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_crc.c#L301

Comment: I don't wan't to get into arguments on the design of the API. I'll be the first to admit that ST libraries are not high quality. However, from the technical point of view, KamilCuk has the right answer on how to use `HAL_CRC_Accumulate()`.

Comment: @Armandas, yes agreed that under the proper conditions that code is only executed when hcrc->InputDataFormat == CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_WORDS.  However, you have the benefit of seeing the function.  If this was in a library, that might not be the case.  My point is that the function prototype is the contract with the caller and you can't make assumptions beyond what you see in the prototype.  If the prototype specifies a pointer to uint32_t data, then you must assume it wants 32-bit aligned data and always pass it compliant data.

Comment: @Amandas, and just one more thing.  Anyone can change data in the ST structures to their hearts desire.  There is nothing to prevent someone from changing hcrc->InputDataFormat to CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_WORDS and calling the function with a misaligned buffer.